# Problems with c runtimes

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm building a cobol executable on the command line, windows server 2008.
(The question is not cobol specific.)

The micro focus cobol building tool uses "msvcrt.lib" for linking, I cannot 
change this c runtime lib setting.

The cobol exe gets also linked with one of our c libraries.
I'm building this c lib with the Visual Studio 2010 compiler and the "/MD" option.

The cobol linking tool prints the following error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___mktime64
```

With which option should I build our c library in order to have no problems with the "msvcrt.lib" lib.

Thanks alot in advance